# Populating UIPickerview values from CoreData in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, uipickerview, swift5

I am trying to populate a `UIPicker` with data that is stored in `coreData`. they way i have gone about this is i have set up a global variable array and when the screen loads a fetch request is sent to core data which populates the global array. The `UIPicker` then reads this global array and populates itself with its array of strings.

the problem is that the `UIPicker` populates fine the first time i load it, but then the second time i get the original entries repeated, and the 3rd time and 4th etc...

1. global array:

   `var savedWorkoutNamesPulled = [String]()`
2. `UIPicker` set up:

   ```
   //needed picker function (number of columns in picker view)
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }

   //needed picker function (number of rows in pickr view)
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    savedWorkoutNamesPulled.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    //setting exercisesInSelectedWorkout(exercise names within workout) to the elements of the uipicker
    let row = savedWorkoutNamesPulled[row]
    return row
    }
   ```
3. Calling coredata function:

   ```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    //calling function that deals show picker
    showUiPicker()

    //going into core data swift file and calling a function (this function sets global array to fill workout names into picker view)
    print("your workouts are as follows")
    CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.retrieveWorkoutDataFromCoreData()
   ```

   }
4. The core data function that appends values to global array:

   ```
    func retrieveWorkoutDataFromCoreData() -> [Contact]{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ContactsData")
    let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    var contacts = [Contact]()
    for data in result as! [NSManagedObject]{
        guard let id = data.value(forKey: "id") as? String else {continue}
        guard let fullName = data.value(forKey: "fullName") as? String else {continue}
        guard let excercise = data.value(forKey: "excersizes") as? [Exercise] else {continue}
        var contact = Contact(id: id, fullname: fullName, exercises: excercise)
        contact.id = id

        contacts.append(contact)

        print(fullName)
        print(id)

        savedWorkoutNamesPulled.append(fullName)

    }
    return contacts
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by just by setting the array to nothing when the view was dismissed.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        savedWorkoutNamesPulled = []
    }
```